# How to synchronize all elemnts in arraylists based on the first one

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

This is the code I've written so far. But somehow, the size of arrayList is increasing as well.

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,3,2,4));
ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4,2,3,1));

for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
    if(!a.get(i).equals(b.get(i))){
        if(!b.get(i).equals(c.get(i))){
            b.add(a.get(i), b.get(i));
            c.add(a.get(i), c.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I want array lists 'b' and 'c' to be synchronised with elements order as in 'a' arrayList such that at the end the output will be [1,2,3,4] in all cases

Comment: `b = new ArrayList<>(a); c = new ArrayList<>(a);`... It's not quite clear what exactly are your requirements. Are the arrays equal in size? If not, what do you want to do with the elements not present in `a`?

Comment: I believe you want to use  b.set(i,a.get(i));

Comment: If elements on index `i` are not the same in 3 arrays, then add `b[i]` at `i` to `b` and `c[i]` at `i` to `c`. That does not make any sense.

Comment: the size of arraylist will always be the same

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Why do you want it such that `a`, `b` and `c` are equal to eachother?

Comment: it's not creating a new arraylist, but the elements inside should be changed

Comment: if `a` is always ordered you can just use `b.sort()` and `c.sort()`

Comment: And the contents of the list is always the same? Just with a different order? If so, why not just say `ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>(a);` and so on?

Comment: if b and c will always be same as a, why not make new arrays with elements same as that of a?

Comment: what if the elements inside  Arraylist are hashmap

Comment: @G.Brown don't use a `List` of `Map`s but rather create your own class and then have a `List<YourClass>`

Comment: @G.Brown It's still not clear what you want and why you want it. Doesn't `b = new ArrayList<>(a); c = new ArrayList<>(a);` work for you?

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronized"? Do you mean that if order of elements in list A will change should it *automatically* change order of elements in lists B and C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to admit, that I don't know what the purpose of this is, but it gives the expected result.
If you need some other/additional functionality, please clarify your question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 2, 4));
    ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 3, 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (!a.get(i).equals(b.get(i))) {
            b.set(i, a.get(i));
        }
        if (!a.get(i).equals(c.get(i))) {
            c.set(i, a.get(i));
        }
    }

    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(b.toArray()));
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(c.toArray()));
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Sure you can compare both lists in one step and set both if one isn't equal - but this means c is also changed(which doesn't hurt) if only b needs to be adjusted and c doesn't realy:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 2, 4));
    ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 3, 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if ((!a.get(i).equals(b.get(i))) || (!a.get(i).equals(c.get(i)))) {
            b.set(i, a.get(i));
            c.set(i, a.get(i));
        }
    }

    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(b.toArray()));
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(c.toArray()));
}
```

Comment: can we do this in a single if condition? What if there are 6 or 7 arrayLists?

Comment: you can but it does unnecessary changes in the lists.

Comment: If you have multiple lists you will need to check all of them. I guess you cannot skip one. You could use a loop however

Comment: I think it will be difficult to use it for 7 (or) dynamically increasing arraylists

Comment: You need to put your requirements down to answer the question whether there are other, more optimal ways. Sure, you have to take care that the indices match up and sure you have to iterate over the lists. But e.g. It might be more efficent if you just look at changend elements and adjust all arrays to the changed ones ... I only can't say if that is possible/makes sense in your particular case as I don't know your particular scenario.

Comment: size of all arraylists is same and the number of arraylists increases dynamically. These two are my requirements

Comment: if it only increases but never decreases or change previous elements I would create an update method, that simply adjust/add the new elements. But like I said: only possible if the previous elements in the lists don't change.